# Maximal spectrum of a ring is quasi-compact in Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Show that the maximal spectrum of $R$ is quasi-compact under Zariski topology.

I tried by taking an open cover $\{ D(I_i) | I \in \Lambda \}$ of $\operatorname{Max} R$. Then $\operatorname{Max} R \subseteq \{ D(I_i) \mid I \in \Lambda \} \implies \operatorname{Max} R \subseteq \operatorname{Spec}(R) \setminus V(\sum I_i)$

But I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Here is a link related to the max-spectrum: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132854/why-is-better-to-work-with-the-spectrum-of-prime-ideals-than-with-the-maximal-on/3971302#3971302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce to the claim that $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is quasi-compact.

Suppose $\{D(I_i)\}$ covers $\operatorname{MaxSpec} R$. Then $V(\sum I_i)\subset \operatorname{Spec} R$ is a closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Spec} R$, so it is quasi-compact. Therefore if it's non-empty, it must contain a closed point. But such a closed point is a point of $\operatorname{MaxSpec} R$, and $\{D(I_i)\}$ were assumed to cover $\operatorname{MaxSpec} R$, so it must be the case that $\{D(I_i)\}$ cover $\operatorname{Spec} R$ as well, so we're down to just showing that $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is quasi-compact. This is well-covered on MSE ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783267/question-regarding-open-covers-in-zariski-topology-distinguished-opens-of-affin) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872170/proof-that-an-affine-scheme-is-quasi-compact)) and elsewhere, like [Stacks 00E8](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00E8).